# How to get Selenium to pass Javascript generated source-code to Scrapy?

Tags: selenium, scrapy

I have built a basic Scrapy Spider which scrapes a site's product category page, opens all the individual product pages and scrapes some product information. When there are multiple pages for one category the site uses Javascript to refresh the product list (the URL does not change).

I am trying to use Selenium to access the JS generated pages.

```
import time
import scrapy
from myscraper.items import myscraperItem
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

class websiteSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "myspider"
    allowed_domains = ["example.com"]
    start_urls = (
        'http://www.example.com/cat1',
    )

    def __init__(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
        self.driver.implicitly_wait(10)

    def parse(self, response):
        self.driver.get(response.url)

        while True:
            next = self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector("li.active a#page_right div")

            try:
                for href in response.css('div.productlist h3 a::attr(href)'):
                    url = response.urljoin(href.extract())
                    yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse_product_page)
                time.sleep(10)
                next.click()
            except:
                break

    def parse_product_page(self, response):
      ...
```

When I run this I only scrape products from the first page, how can I push the newly generated source code for pages 2 onwards from Selenium into Scrapy? I have tried a few things involving:

```
 hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
```

But I don't really understand it, any help would be much appreciated!!

Thanks

Comment: I'm sure you can do it without using selenium, open your network tab and click on the next page, a request will be made and will receive receive a response with the objects you desire. You can make this request directly. If you want further help provide the link of the page in question.

Comment: Thanks @RafaelAlmeida - any idea for http://www.homebase.co.uk/en/homebaseuk/decorating/paint-and-decorating-supplies/interior-emulsion-paint ?